# Is there someone who tried to gather horcruxes like how Tom Riddle did?

Tags: harry-potter

(This post literally pertains to someone who ever tried to "think" of making a horcrux. Not just long ago before Tom started gathering horcrux, I am ESPECIALLY PERTAINING to those who have thought of it, when Voldemort vanished.

Gathering horcruxes is one of the most unforgivable and violent offense in nature. As Voldemort tried to obtain immortality, he also wants the idea of 'no one can ever defeat me'.

Dumbledore convinced Harry to try each and every possible way to collect Slughorn's memory about that night when Tom came asking about horcrux, that Voldemort is **the only one who had successfully turned seven significant things, (diary, diadem, cup, snake, ring, locket, and unintentionally... Harry himself**).

> "By an act of evil — the supreme act of evil. By commiting murder. 
>   Killing rips the soul apart. The wizard intent upon creating a Horcrux would 
>   use the damage to his advantage: He would encase the torn portion —"

...

> "You think he succeeded then, sir?" asked Harry. "He made a Horcrux? 
>   And that's why he didn't die when he attacked me? He had a Horcrux hidden 
>   somewhere? A bit of his soul was safe?" 
>   "A bit... or more," said Dumbledore. "You heard Voldemort, what he 
>   particularly wanted from Horace was an opinion on what would happen to 
>   the wizard who created more than one Horcrux, what would happen to the 
>   wizard so determined to evade death that he would be prepared to murder 
>   many times, rip his soul repeatedly, so as to store it in many, separately 
>   concealed Horcruxc. No book would have given him that information. ***As far 
>   as I know — as far, I am sure, as Voldemort knew — no wizard had ever 
>   done more than tear his soul in two."***

```
Excerpt from Hp HBP book 6.
```

It was a really dangerous thing to do... horcruxes. But Tom Riddle managed to turn and made 7 horcruxes, splitting his soul into seven hidden pieces.

Having said this, is there any chance that another bad wizard tried to gather horcruxes? For some reason, if that wizard tries to gain immortality, he also wants to be undefeatable, higher than Voldemort's rose to power.

***Did someone tried to make a horcrux, specifically, did someone had that kind of idea pop into his/her head, just to gain immortality? Just like what young Tom Riddle desires?***

Comment: @JasonBaker before you mark this post as a duplicate, did you read this post? I specifically said "did someone had that kind of idea pop into his/her head, just to gain immortality? Just like what young Tom Riddle desires?". There's a huge difference between that post you marked that has a duplicate, pertaining to this post. It's not a duplicate.

Comment: Again, sir, answers make dupes. You specifically asked 'did someone have that kind of an idea'. Well, with respect, the answer is obviously yes they did, because the linked question gives an example. As before, you do ask many branching questions, the answers to most of which are inferable from the linked question. If you want to avoid questions being closed as duplicate, don't get upset. A dupe closure is not censure, it isn't a criticism. There's nothing wrong with your question - it's so good, other people have wondered about it too! But we close as duplicate to keep the place nice and tidy

Comment: If however you want to avoid that (which is fair enough), what you need to do is focus your question down to one single question which isn't answered elsewhere. Alas, I fear that if you do that, your question is likely to be very broad, since you seem to be asking, did anyone else even think of making a horcrux? Well the answer is obviously, yeah, probably. But the only way to answer it is to provide a list of examples. And we tend to avoid open-ended list questions.

Comment: I do not remember reading that Voldemort invented horcruxes, so there must have been other wizards who had done it. Perhaps it was accidental, when a wizard committed murder.

Comment: Yes willow rex it is possible that it is just. But i wonder if how did they invent the spell used for horcruxes

Comment: my comment suggests that they did invent the spell by accident.

Comment: Well, the spell for murdering is quite different for the charm used for hiding your soul in that object, considering you killed someone.